# Proxy is not working on port no 443 but Working with Port no 80

Tags: ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, mod-proxy

**I create a virtual host with port no 80 and also used ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse on port no 80.  Proxy is working perfect with port no 80**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  site.com
ServerAlias www.site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.com
<Directory /var/www/html/site.com>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia Full
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3005/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3005/
```

**I create a virtual host with port no 443 with SSL and also used ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse on port no 443.  Proxy is not working.**

```
 <VirtualHost  *:443>
         ServerAlias www.site.com
        ServerName site.com
 
       ServerAdmin admin@site.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.com
       
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /home/ubuntu/site.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile  /home/ubuntu/site.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile  /home/ubuntu/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/devapitest.fareboutique-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/devapitest.fareboutique-access.log combined

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia Full
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3005/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3005/

</VirtualHost>

  ****SSL is working perfect but proxy is not working****
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code working fine

just added inside virtual host  443

```
<VirtualHost  *:443>

     ServerAlias www.site.com
    ServerName site.com

   ServerAdmin admin@site.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.com
   
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /home/ubuntu/site.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /home/ubuntu/site.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /home/ubuntu/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/devapitest.fareboutique-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/devapitest.fareboutique-access.log combined

   SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:3005/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:3005/
   </VirtualHost>
  **SSL and proxy is working perfect**
```